# How to approach this question?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, electromagnetism, divergence-theorem

[I have been trying this, but I do not understand how to get the gradient of the triple integration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxJDk.png)

> If a region $V$ bounded by a surface $S$ has a continuous charge (or mass) distribution of density $\rho$, the potential $\phi(P)$ at a point $P$ is defined by $\phi = \iiint_V \frac{\rho dV}{r}$. Deduce the following under suitable assumptions:
>
> 1. $\iint_S \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf S = 4 \pi \iiint_V \rho d V$, where $\mathbf E = - \nabla \phi$.
> 2. $\nabla^2\phi = - 4 \pi \rho$ (Poisson's equation) at all points $P$ where charges exist, and $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ (Laplace's equation) where no charges exist.

Now, I tried to use Divergence theorem. But I do not understand how do I find gradient of triple integration. Thanking you all.

Here is how I tried.Assuming $\rho$ to be a function of r.

> $\phi = \iiint_V \frac{\rho dV}{r}$
>
> $\nabla\phi = \iiint_V \nabla(\frac{\rho }{r})dV$
>
> $\nabla\phi = \iiint_V (\frac{\rho'\mathbf r}{r}+\rho\frac{-\mathbf r}{r^3})dV$
>
> $\nabla^2\phi = \iiint_V \nabla(\frac{\rho'\mathbf r}{r}+\rho\frac{-\mathbf r}{r^3})dV$
>
> $\nabla^2\phi = \iiint_V (\rho''\frac{\mathbf r . \mathbf r}{r^2}+(\rho'\frac{\mathbf r}{r}+\rho(\frac{3}{r^3}+\mathbf r\frac{-3\mathbf r}{r^5})))dV$
>
> $\nabla^2\phi = \iiint_V (\rho''+(\rho'\frac{\mathbf r}{r}))dV$
>
> $\nabla^2\phi = \iiint_V (\rho''+\rho'\hat{r}))dV$

Here, if I assume $\rho$ to be constant then $\nabla^2\phi$ is equal to zero.
But my result are not upto the expectation of the question.
I followed as I was advised but results are unsatisfactory.
If there is any mistake in my calculation ,please correct me.

Thanking you

Comment: Please see the FAQ on how to ask a good question.  Good questions generate good answers.

Comment: @shivank Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as [is explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it is good that you shared some of your thoughts on the problem, but it would be helpful if you could address any of the following questions. Where did you encounter this problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you already know about $E$? Do you assume, for example, $\iint_SE\cdot dS=4\pi Q$?

Comment: @J.G. it is mentioned in question.E=−∇ϕ .

Comment: If that's all you have, you really need to assume $2$, then use it to prove $1$, not to prove both, let alone in the order $1,\,2$.

Comment: @J.G. I do not understand how to get the gradient of triple integration. phi is a triple integration . And I need to calculate its gradient. How will I get that. Please, correct me If I said something incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For part 1, the idea is to use the divergence theorem to write
$$
\iint_S \mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf S = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \mathbf E\,dV.
$$
You should be able to simplify the expression $\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \nabla \cdot (-\nabla \phi) = -\nabla^2 \phi$ to end up with the integrand $4 \pi \rho$.

For part 2, you will have already found that $-\nabla^2 \phi = 4 \pi \rho$ in part 1. Multiplying both sides gives you the desired result $\nabla^2 \phi = -4 \pi \rho$, which simply becomes $\nabla^2\phi = 0$ at points $P$ for which $\rho(P) = 0$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but my main doubt was how ∇2ϕ  is ending up with the integrand 4πρ?? I do not understand how can I get the gradient of triple integral.

Comment: @shivankanchal Note that the gradient can be moved into the integral. That is,
$$
\nabla \iiint_V \frac{\rho dV}{r} = \iiint_V \nabla\left[ \frac{\rho}{r}\right] dV.
$$

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried to solve. Please, can you tell me where I went wrong.